# How to set up 301 redirect to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-301

I have a domain for which I would like to set up both a www and non-www redirect to https://newdomain.com.

So olddomain.com and www.olddomain.com should go to https://shinynewdomain.com.

```
#redirect http non-www to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#redirect https non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is the code I'm using, and it sends me to a domain parking page at my registrar instead of the new domain at a different host.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: _“it sends me to a domain parking page at my registrar instead of the new domain at a different host”_ - you’re misunderstanding how things work here. All this does is tell your browser, which URL it should request instead. Whether you then get a “parked domain” page, or the actual content you expect to see - that doesn’t have anything to do with the redirect any more. This is a new request - and either the DNS resolves the host name to the new server correctly, or it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do the redirection of your old website to your new website. If your website is made using wordpress then it will be more easy to achieve 301 redirections.

**Method 1:**

1. In Wordpress, what you can do is install the plugin **Simple 301 Redirect**.
2. Setup the plugin as you like.
3. Then you will find options in Settings after activating it.

**Method 2**

1. Another is using some code line in the `.htaccess` file.
2. In the web directory settings, you will find the access of `.htaccess` file.
3. Open the file in the editor and use the code below.

To redirect a single page: Redirect 301 /old-file.html http://www.example.com/new-file.html
To redirect to a new website: Redirect 301 / http://www.new-example.com/